# When multiple upload is finished in p:fileUpload?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a multiple `p:fileUpload`, I need to upload from 1 to N files on server, after uploading I need to know how many files were uploaded and then start processing method. How can I know when all files are uploaded? I have not found any event for multiple upload, there is event only for individual files, `oncomplete` in `p:fileUpload` also works for every file individually. I had idea to use additional button to invoke processing method, but this is not safe, because user can push this button before all files are uploaded. Who can advice me something?

Answer (score 16):

For other people who may face the same problem.

The file upload component has 'files' property which contain the list of files to be uploaded. As soon as a file uploaded it is removed from the 'files' array, thus when last file is uploaded the 'files' will be empty. This could be used to detect the moment when the last file is uploaded. Afterwards you can trigger remote command to do whatever you want.

Code example:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload id="files"
             widgetVar="fileUploadWidget"
             mode="advanced"
             multiple="true"
             oncomplete="handleMultiFileUploadRequest(PF('fileUploadWidget'), validateFiles);"/>

    <p:remoteCommand name="validateFiles" actionListener="#{Your action}"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMultiFileUploadRequest(fileupload, remoteButton) {
            if (fileupload.files.length === 0) {
                if (remoteButton) {
                    remoteButton();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What's the type for the fileUploadWidget bean attribute?

Comment: @bruno the fileUploadWidget is client side only and just a reference to the JS object

Answer (score -1):

You can validate a modal dialog, until you finish the process, and ends when you close it.